# Need to to see if current user is the same user that created the record being edited

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a request process (custom list) in SharePoint that need to implement some business rules.  First rule is to only have the current user be able to edit the record along with some administrators.  The problem with using the OOB, "**Create and Edit access**" is that when an a user is editing a record that is not theirs, SharePoint does not warn them until they attempt a save.  That's too late to tell a user that news, so I need to enforce my own security so the user is not allowed to edit.

My code to get the current user:

```
function SetCurrentUsernameToPeoplePicker()
{
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  this.website = ctx.get_web();
  this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
  ctx.load(currentUser);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.defaultUserSuccess), 
  Function.createDelegate(this, this. defaultUserFail));
}

function defaultUserSuccess (sender, args)
{
  var loginName = currentUser.get_loginName();
  console.log('login='+loginName );
}
```

I could not figure out how to get the user from the Requestor Name people picker on the screen, so I attempted to use CAMEL query to get it.  I have the object, but can't get the loginName to compare.  I have the following code:

```
 function retrieveListItems() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('BSMRequests');
    var recordId = "14";
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>'+ recordId +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'); 
    collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                                                           Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
  }

  function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
      var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    console.log('requestor='+oListItem.get_item('Requestor_x0020_Name'));
    }
  }
```

I need either a way to get the LoginName for the Requestor Name field for this record or another means of comparing the current user with that of the user who created this record.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,Requestor_x0020_Name is a user field.

The jsom return oListItem.get_item('Requestor_x0020_Name') as SP.FieldUserValue object, you could get user id by `oListItem.get_item('Requestor_x0020_Name').get_lookupId()` or user name by `oListItem.get_item('Requestor_x0020_Name').get_lookupValue()`.

For this case, I think you could compare the user id.